# Reader for .txt file

Tags: text-editing, read-only, pdf-reader

I want to read .txt files but not editing them.

Not in the command line, so not `more` and similar utilities.

I would like to open like if it were a .pdf file, but without converting to a PDF, so not `pandoc` and similiar utilities.

My case is: I have downloaded all the RFCs so I'm looking for the most convenient way to read them offline.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [softwarerecs.se],  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Text files have no formatting, so this question makes no sense. In addition, all modern OS installs have a GUI-based txt reader.

Comment: What's wrong with just double-clicking them & them opening in whatever your default text editor is? You're not forced to edit, you can just close after reading.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Software Recommendations SE.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows SumatraPDF reader can read many ebooks such as RFC1.txt however as they are also published as PDF those are better layout. Look closer using zoom. the PDF is as designed whilst the txt is not as it is converted to A5 layout and then reflows to an extra page! (earlier version such as 3.1/3.2 would have better text control).

[image]

WordPad would be the best viewer on windows as you can fettle it more than MS NotePad, but plain Notepad, too is perfect for TXT reading / printing to PDF as it can be programmed via scripting.

[image]